# Unity custom map displayed incorrect

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

Currently I am working on a little location-based game. I use the map box asset, to display the map. For that I changed the style url of the map object in unity. When I start the game it looks quit ugly and not like I designed it on the map box website.

The design on the map box website:
[image]

The map in the game:
[image]

The default style:
[image]
Someone knows what the problem could be? I followed the tutorial on the map box website and they told me just to change the style url.

Comment: Is there a default style? If so how does it look?

Comment: @Thalthanas Added in the OP

Comment: Guess you are missing something, have you checked [mapbox sdk for Unity](https://www.mapbox.com/unity-sdk/tutorials/) . In part 2 and 3 it shows how to add 3d buildings and style them

Comment: And also it may be related to your location. Don't know where is at right now, but you can use manhattan or other big areas for 3d building info

Comment: @Thalthanas these parts are needed if you want to add vector buildings or good looking terrains. I followed this tutorial: https://www.mapbox.com/help/unity-custom-map-style/